# Orientate a rotation Vector in 3D space to face a destination

Tags: vb.net, xna, rotation

I got two position vectors in three dimensional space:

```
Dim Position As Vector3
Dim Destination As Vector3
```

I also got a rotation vector, which is used to rotate the object. It contains the Yaw, Pitch and Roll values (=> ranges from 0 to PI * 2)

I now want this rotation vector to point to the correct orientation, so that the object in the end points at the Destination vector, being at the Position vector.

I have no idea how to accomplish this though.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but have not posted it, because it's not quite clear what you're doing.  Are you trying to get a transformation facing the desired direction and then apply yaw, pitch and roll?  Are you aware that the result will depend on the order in which you apply these rotations?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did 3D stuff, hence this is going to be a conceptual-only answer.

You can construct three orthogonal unit vectors and combine those as the rows in a matrix.  That matrix will be your transformation.  You know one vector already...

```
forward = to_point - from_point
```

Now you need an "up" and a "right" vector, which can be calculated using cross-product, provided you have some sort of world reference vector (otherwise your solution space is infinite).  For example, the "up" vector should be defined.

This does mean that your solution may suffer from *gimbal lock* if your "forward" vector becomes too parallel with your "up" vector.  In that case, the cross product will come out very small (or zero) and everything will break.  That's just because you're trying to solve a system with two degrees of freedom and using an assumption to fill one of those.

Anyway...

```
right = forward cross up
```

Then you can fix the up-vector:

```
up = right cross forward
```

The ordering of the cross-product operations above assume a right-handed system.  If your world is left-handed, then reverse the ordering of the two vectors being crossed.

So, now you have three orthogonal vectors that represent your object's transform.  Slap these into a matrix.  The rows (or columns, depending on which side of the equation the matrix is applied) will depend on how you define your co-ordinate system.  I used to have X being right, Y being forward, and Z being up.

Now that you have your object's 'neutral' rotation matrix, you can apply ordinary pitch, roll and yaw rotations to it using standard matrix transformations.  Indeed you can construct the "local" rotation matrix by applying pitch, roll and yaw to the identity matrix, and then multiply that with the matrix you constructed earlier.